Should we ask Ravencoin questions on Bitcoin?
I'm proposing a new site for a cryptocurrency called Ravencoin, which is a slightly modified and more private version of Bitcoin. Because it's foundation is based off of the Bitcoin project, should questions on the Ravencoin system be asked on Bitcoin Stack Exchange, as it is very similar in terms of encryption, blockchains, halving processes, etc? Or, should I continue in creating a separate proposal for the Ravencoin cryptocurrency?
Proposal: Ravencoin

If someone wanted to ask a question that applied to Ravencoin the same way it applies to Bitcoin, it could be phrased so it is applicable to Bitcoin and would probably get an answer quickly. Questions specific only to other cryptocurrencies are off-topic and would get closed as such.

Ok. I'll keep the proposal, as there are some significant differences.
